# std::weak_ptr::operator= confusion

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, swap

While looking at [`std::weak_ptr::operator=` on cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/operator%3D), I realized I don't understand what the explanations for overloads (1-3) mean. Namely, it's stated that

```
template< class Y > 
weak_ptr& operator=( const shared_ptr<Y>& r ) noexcept;
```

is equivalent with

```
std::weak_ptr<T>(r).swap(*this)
```

How can that be? Isn't `std::weak_ptr<T>(r)` a rvalue (a temporary), and `.swap(*this)` refers to its instance, i.e., swapping with itself? I would've thought it should perhaps be

```
std::weak_ptr<T>().swap(r)
```

What exactly is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::weak_ptr<T>(r)
```

creates a temporary `weak_ptr` that points to the same object as `r`;

```
.swap(*this)
```

exchanges the values of the temporary with the current instance, making the current instance point to the same object as `r` and the temporary point to whatever the current instance used to;

```
;
```

destroys the temporary, so there is now one fewer `weak_ptr` pointing to the object that the current instance used to point to.

Comment: Isn't the current instance the temporary itself?

Comment: Current instance may or may not represent a temporary, but its "temporariness" is completely irrelevant to the question being asked. `*this` is an lvalue, since it is addressable.

Comment: You're right, my misunderstanding, `std::weak_ptr<T>().swap(r)` is actually invoked inside the member function...